# How to mount windows share on linux with specific credentials and specific linux user ownership?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, cifs

I have linux user `lUser` (uid=123) that is in the group `lGroup` (guid=145). I have windows user `wUser` that has full access to the share. I want to automount that share on linux machine and give `lUser` full access to that directory. I've edited `/etc/fstab`:

> //192.168.1.2/WinShare /home/root/WinShare cifs
>   username=**wUser**,password=**Password**,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,uid=**123**,gid=**145**
>   0       0

I am doing `sudo mount -a` and this folder is still  owned by root.

Then I created users on both machines with the same name and password. After that I added following line to the `fstab`

> //192.168.1.2/WinShare /home/user/WinShare cifs
>   iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,uid=1000,gid=1000    0       0

It is still mounted as root

I've also tried to do:

> //192.168.1.2/WinShare /home/user/WinShare ntfs-3g
>   users,permissions,auto 0 0

still the same ...

Answer (score 0):

As per [`mount.cifs`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) documentation, the `uid` and `gid` parameters only work when the server does not support UNIX extensions. The `forceuid` and `forcegid` parameters prevent this behavior. If you connect to a NAS, it might use Samba too.

You can also specify UID and GID by using the actual user/group name.

There’s also [this Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/859259), perhaps it’s still relevant.

Comment: I've created user with the same name and password on the both machines and then trying to add following line: //192.168.1.2/WinShare /home/user/WinShare cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,uid=1000,gid=1000    0       0
and still it is mounted as root

Comment: I've edited the question, added 1 more option I've tried

Comment: I was able to change ownership from root to my current user, but not to the one I needed....

Comment: Again: Did you try `forceuid`? This is a yes/no question.

Comment: yes. I was able to change ownership from root to my current user but not to the one I needed.